# Closing percent MATH in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, math, average

I want to do math in a query, and was wondering if its better to do it in PHP or MYSQL.
Also, if I choose MYSQL can anyone help me with the query.

So far I have

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) as total, booker, appdate,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status='DNS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) book,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status!='DNS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) tot
  FROM appts WHERE WEEK(app_date)= WEEK(CURDATE()) GROUP BY booker
```

I want one more stat from this query.
I want to  do `book / (book+tot)`
But obviously only if `book!=0` or `tot!=0`, since obviously I don't want to divide anything by zero.

Is there a way to do this in a MYSQL query??

I want my output to be.....

```
       book  | 14
       tot   | 25
       hold  | 35%
```

Id also like to ORDER BY the hold percent from highest to lowest.  Is this possible????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you ask for using a subquery, like this:

```sql
SELECT *, IF(book + tot, 100*book/(book + tot), NULL) AS hold
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) as total, booker, appdate,
  SUM(status='DNS') book, SUM(status!='DNS') tot
  FROM appts WHERE WEEK(app_date)= WEEK(CURDATE()) GROUP BY booker
) AS subquery
ORDER BY hold DESC
```

Note that in several places I'm using the fact that MySQL uses numbers for logical values. So you can sum up conditions without `CASE`, and you can write a formula for `IF` without `<> 0` check.

Answer (score 1):

Naive method:

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(*) as total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='DNS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) book,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status!='DNS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) tot,

    IF(  ( SUM(CASE WHEN status!='DNS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
           SUM(CASE WHEN status='DNS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ) = 0,
          0,
          SUM(CASE WHEN status='DNS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /
           ( SUM(CASE WHEN status!='DNS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
             SUM(CASE WHEN status='DNS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) )
    ) AS hold
FROM appts
WHERE WEEK(app_date) = WEEK(CURDATE()) GROUP BY booker
ORDER BY hold;
```

Or in order not to repeat your aliases, use a subquery:

```sql
SELECT *, IF (book + tot = 0, 0, book / (book + tot) * 100)
FROM (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) as total,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status='DNS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) book,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status!='DNS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) tot,
    FROM appts
    WHERE WEEK(app_date) = WEEK(CURDATE()) GROUP BY booker
) AS subq
ORDER BY hold;
```

Or, more cleverly :) (`book` + `tot` = `total`)

```sql
SELECT *, IF (total = 0, 0, book / total * 100)
FROM (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) as total,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status='DNS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) book,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status!='DNS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) tot,
    FROM appts
    WHERE WEEK(app_date) = WEEK(CURDATE()) GROUP BY booker
) AS subq
ORDER BY hold;
```

And, just for fun, the hackishly compactest form:

```sql
SELECT *, COALESCE(book / total * 100, 0) AS hold -- a division by 0 returns NULL
FROM (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) total,
        SUM(status='DNS') book, -- boolean "true" is internally integer "1"
        SUM(status!='DNS') tot,
    FROM appts
    WHERE WEEK(app_date) = WEEK(CURDATE()) GROUP BY booker
) AS subq
ORDER BY hold;
```

Comment: @KyleK By the way, `total` will never be 0, because if `COUNT(*) = 0`, then there is no row at all :)